# How to run a list of tasks where some of the tasks run sequentially to each other and one runs in parallel to them in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executorservice, sequential

How do I run a list of tasks where some of them run sequentially while one runs parallel to these sequential tasks. At the end I want to combine the result of these sequential tasks & parallel task to then pass to a list of sequential task again.

For eg: Let say, I have 6 tasks - t1 , t2, t3, t4, t5, t6.

I want to run t1->t2->t3 sequentially while t4 can run parallel to these. Once all of them have completed, I want to feed the output to t5->t6.

Note: The number of tasks can vary so I am looking for a generic answer where I can pass the list of tasks that have to be run in sequential & tasks that can be run in parallel.

Looking for suggestions on how can I achieve it in Java?

Comment: There are few conceptually different ways to do so and it's unclear from your question what have you tried, what does and what doesn't work for you. Like, have you tried `CompletableFuture` and `Executors`?

Comment: I haven't tried them yet. Open to any of the ways to achieve this.

Comment: I guess you should start with something that would be much easier to help when you have a particular implementation problem

Comment: “I want to feed the output to t5->t6.”  What output is that?  A list of values returned from t1, t2, and t3?  The value returned from t4?  A combination of them?

Comment: A combination of them. So each of these tasks set their output in a List<OUTPUT> object. t5,t6 (the set of final seq tasks) need output from all of the previous task to operate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this may be what you want:

```java
ExecutorService parallel = Executors.newCachedThreadpool();
ExecutorService sequentialGlobal = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
// first, we add a a parallel executor which runs two sets of tasks in parallel
sequentialGlobal.execute( () -> {
  parallel.execute( () -> { //add the first set of tasks to run sequentially in one thread
    ExecutorService sequential = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    for(Runnable r: sequentials) sequential.execute(r); //sequentials would contain t1, t2 and t3 in the example
  }
  parallel.execute(t4); //and the other in another thread
  //next we await the termination of those 2 threads
  parallel.awaitTermination(timeout, timeUint); //select some value that fits your need
});
// we add the remaining tasks to run sequentially
for (Runnable r: lastSequentials) { //t5, t6
  sequentialGlobal.execute(r);
}
// and await termination.
sequentialGlobal.awaitTermination(timeout, timeUnit);
```

It works this way: the sequential executors, are single thread executors that [guarantee sequential execution of the tasks in the order they are added](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--). And the parallel executor creates a thread for each task.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

- To run tasks in parallel just executed the on a `ExecutorService` and a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` could be a good default choice.
- When you want to run asynchronous tasks sequentially in the same thread just use `.thenApply(...)`
- Use `.join()` to stop and wait for a result of the execution
- Use `CompletableFuture.allOf` to have a single `CompletableFuture` of few

In you case it could be something like:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

Supplier<String> task1 = { "task1" }
Function<String, String> task2 = { it + " -> task2" }
Function<String, String> task3 = { it + " -> task3" }
Supplier<String> task4 = { "task4" }

CompletableFuture<String> task3result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task1, executor)
        .thenApply(task2)
        .thenApply(task3)

CompletableFuture<String> task4result  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task4, executor)

Function<Void, String> merge123and4 = {
    "[[" + task3result.join() + "] + " + task4result.join() + "]"
}
Function<String, String> task5 = { it + " -> task5" }
Function<String, String> task6 = { it + " -> task6" }

// or instead of .allOf().thenApplyAsync() you could simply use a new .supplyAsync()
CompletableFuture<String> result = CompletableFuture.allOf(task3result, task4result)
    .thenApplyAsync(merge123and4, executor)
    .thenApply(task5)
    .thenApply(task6)

System.out.println("Result: " + result.join())
```

Prints:

```
Result: [[task1 -> task2 -> task3] + task4] -> task5 -> task6
```